# 2005 Saturn Ion running rough after running for 30 minutes

Tags: engine, rough-idle, saturn, ion

My 2005 Saturn Ion starts and runs great for about 30 minutes or so, then it starts running rough like the mixture is too rich.  I have to let it sit for an hour or two and then it cranks and runs great again.  I replaced the map sensor and both 02 sensors because that's what was coding.  What is wrong with my car?

Comment: Did you replace the MAP and O2 sensors based on a diagnostic scan result or just on a suggestion?

Comment: I had it checked at O'Reilly's

Comment: Again did they say it might be these things or they printed out a report and confirmed these sensors were not working? Anyway go to AutoZone get a full diagnostic scan and share the results. If you can go to GM, the scanning from a dealership device is 100% accurate. It'll be a nominal fee.

Comment: what are the codes?

Comment: Thanks Numair.  O'Reilly only said that these were the codes that were showing up.  They did not say that they were bad.  I made that brilliant choice.  They did not print out any report.  Ben, I don't remember the specific codes, but the map sensor and both 02 sensors showed up on the screen when the guy at O'Reilly's hooked their little scanner up.

Comment: Numair, given the symptoms I described, what would be your guess as to the problem?

Comment: I would suggest having it read again. This time get a report or write down the codes. Having them *now* will help you troubleshoot what is going on *now*.